# How can I echo an at (@) sign in PHP?

Tags: php, escaping, printf, exec, echo

Using PHP, how can I echo an at `(@)` sign?

Ultimately, I'm trying to print out an e-mail address to a shell, that should look like this: `'user@site.com'`, but it ends up looking like this: `'usersite.com'`.

I see that all these (echo, exec, shell_exec, sprintf, vsprintf) behave like this so I suspect I need to escape it in some way?

Comment: Double-quotes will display variable values including line breaks, and single quotes will display the variable names... I tried this but it didn't affect the @ sign.  I'm working in a PHP framework (Symfony, not a twig view but just a function).  I'm also viewing it in a webpage.  Might this affect it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing something wrong, there is no escaping neccessary:

```
echo "user@site.com";
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: something, something, **shell**, something, special circumstance with the shell?

Comment: As I added above, I'm working in Symfony, but I am using straight PHP here (exec, echo...), so don't think that matters does it?  Also, I'm sending it to a browser but the exec command also receives the string with a missing '@', whether I use single- or double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

When echoing to shell, you need to use double quotes if you are using any special characters, @ included.

This will work:

```
echo "user@site.com/n";
```

This will not:

```
echo 'user@site.com/n';
```